# How to change success message of form extension?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using the system extension **form** for small contact forms. The default success message is

> The form has been sent successfully by mail

How can this message and the error message be changed and/or translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your form content element, go to tab *Form*. There you will see the form configuration. In block `postProcessor` add a `message` block:

```
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        recipientEmail = contact@example.com
        senderEmail = form@example.com
        subject = Call me please
        messages {
            success = Thank you! We will call you soon.
            error = Oops! Something went wrong.
        }
    }
}
```